# Use create an record with Active Storage without ActionParameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I try to create a record, with image, directyl with create, and in model

Banner.create(
  start_at: Time.now,
  location: 'site',
  image_fr: File.new("#{Rails.root}/db/seeds/images/banners/pdfs/gift_voucher_bottom.png", 'r'),
  image_de: File.new("#{Rails.root}/db/seeds/images/banners/pdfs/gift_voucher_bottom.png", 'r'),
  width: 595,
  height: nil
)

I must do at creation moment, not with .attach after, because of validation. Can we do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a block to `create`. It’ll be called with the new record before it’s saved:

```
Banner.create(start_at: Time.now, location: 'site', width: 595, height: nil) do |banner|
  Rails.root.join('db/seeds/images/banners/pdfs/gift_voucher_bottom.png').open('rb') do |io|
    banner.image_fr.attach(io: io, filename: 'banner.png', content_type: 'image/png')
  end

  # ...
end
```